# Three solutions to structure a deployment with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, structure

I am currently deploying a new product and came across some problems to structure my Playbook and Roles. I have three different solutions and hope to get some input which path might be the best.

The product is a webapp on a windows server. The following steps are needed to deploy (high level):

- install javajdk
- install tomcat
- install win_service
- configure java regkes
- configure tomcat
- install webapp
- start service

I use static inventories for prod and staging, group_vars, roles (created with ansible-galaxy) so there is some kind of structure.

---

**Solution 1** 
Put everything in one huge playbook. That does not sound well, but has the advantage that you know the variables from previous installations e.g. `tomcat` needs to know where `JAVA_HOME` is... that was with the `javajdk` installation, due to more than one java on the machines there is no global `JAVA_HOME`...

---

**Solution 2** 
Break all out in small roles. Sounds great but roles should be independent from each other. I did not found a method to decouple tasks. Would it make sense to have single roles for e.g. `install_tomcat`, `config_tomcat` and set up a playbook which has the mentioned roles in sequence?

But how does one role know about, e.g. a path name which is needed in the next role. -> Installation sets the path, config needs to know.. I an really unsure to make roles independent.

---

**Solution 3** 
Kind of solution 2. Have a main playbook which contains only roles, split as much as possible to roles. Have independent variable names in `./roles/vars/main.yml`

Somehow(?) find a place higher in the variable precedence with the playbook where all needed `var` definitions go. Internally either path a variable to the role or simply over-rule a role variable.

E.g. a product has a service, the service name is generally part of a path name for `tomcat`. The `tomcat` name should not depend on the service, so there should be a `tomcat_install_path` in the role but also a `service_name` with the product. So in case the playbook for the product is called the service name should be part of the name, the `tomcat_install` is called with a total different deployment there should be no fiddling with a service name.

---

*I would go with Solution 3 but I have not yet found a way to set that up. What is the experts opinion, is solution 3 doable, is one of the other once better or is there a 4th solution?*

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to structure the code as defined in [the Ansible Best Practices document](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html):

[image]

and to follow the structure that major contributors to the ansible galaxy platform use, like [geerlingguy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/geerlingguy/).

If one will follow a significant different structure then it will be really hard in the future to reuse roles from the [ansible galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/) community and one has to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks. And concrete in regards to my question: How will you decouple and reuse e.g. javajdk installation and the reuse of it in a tomcat installation? When they are decoupled than the variables e.g. pat to javaddk will need to be "in" the role. How do you handle this in a tomcat installation with out changing variables all over the place? Is there a common concept to use variable precedence? Is so which?

Comment: I would check ansible galaxy and install a jdk and tomcat role. I will not write a role myself unless it is unavailable. For example, https://github.com/silpion/ansible-tomcat and `ansiblebit.oracle-java`

Comment: Note that I did not test the tomcat role. You could test the tomcat role locally. If that does not work, you could use another tomcat role from galaxy.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: You do programming here. Consider Programming Standards (cleancode) like "package by feature" and build role which are reusable and express the reason of the role.
e.g.

```
roles:
  - role: jdk
  - role: tomcat  
      (contains tasks with 'install tomcat', 'configure tomcat' ) 
      (requires jdk)
  - role: the_wepapp 
      (requires tomcat)
```

Futhermore: The underlying role e.g. the jdk should never know about the tomcat role etc...